# No Material widget found. Hero Animation is not working with TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, extends

I want to achieve this animation with TextField:

[image]

but getting this instead:

[image]

Here is my TextField widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart'; import 'package:move_me_delivery/data/styles.dart';

class SearchTextField extends StatefulWidget {   const SearchTextField({Key? key,
    this.onFocusChange,
    this.focus,
    this.onCancel,
    this.inputDecoration   }) : super(key: key);

  final void Function(bool hasFocus)? onFocusChange;   final FocusNode? focus;   final VoidCallback? onCancel;   final InputDecoration? inputDecoration;




  @override   _SearchTextFieldState createState() =>
_SearchTextFieldState(); }

class _SearchTextFieldState extends State<SearchTextField> {   FocusNode _focus = new FocusNode();

  @override   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focus = widget.focus ?? new FocusNode();
    _focus.addListener(
      (){
        if(widget.onFocusChange != null){
          widget.onFocusChange!(_focus.hasFocus);
        }
      }
    );   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: "search",
      child: Row(
        children: [

          Expanded(
            child: TextField(style: AppTextStyles.body2,
                focusNode: _focus,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(LineAwesomeIcons.search, color: Colors.black,),
                  // suffixIcon: Text("Cancel"),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1))
                ))),

          if(widget.onCancel != null)
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: widget.onCancel,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("Cancel"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );   } }
```

And here is my first screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:move_me_delivery/components/rounded_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:move_me_delivery/components/search_field.dart';
import '../screens.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: RoundedAppBar(title: ""),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 32),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SearchTextField(
              onFocusChange: (val) async {
                if(val){

                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                          transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                          pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => SearchScreen()));

                  // await Get.to(() => SearchScreen());
                }
              },

            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my second screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:move_me_delivery/components/search_field.dart';
import 'package:move_me_delivery/data/styles.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 32),

            child: Column(
              children: [
                SearchTextField(
                  focus: _focusNode,
                  onCancel: (){
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(LineAwesomeIcons.search, color: Colors.black,),
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1))
                  ),
                ),


              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My console:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building TextField(focusNode: FocusNode#0fba2, decoration: InputDecoration(prefixIcon: Icon(IconData(U+0F002), color: Color(0xff000000)), filled: true, fillColor: Color(0xffffffff), border: OutlineInputBorder()), style: TextStyle(inherit: true, color: Color(0xff000000), size: 15.0, weight: 400, style: normal), dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, UnmanagedRestorationScope], state: _TextFieldState#43a28):
No Material widget found.

TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them.

To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.

The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was: TextField
  focusNode: FocusNode#0fba2
  decoration: InputDecoration(prefixIcon: Icon(IconData(U+0F002), color: Color(0xff000000)), filled: true, fillColor: Color(0xffffffff), border: OutlineInputBorder())
  style: TextStyle(inherit: true, color: Color(0xff000000), size: 15.0, weight: 400, style: normal)
  dirty
  dependencies: [MediaQuery, UnmanagedRestorationScope]
  state: _TextFieldState#43a28
The ancestors of this widget were: 
  : Expanded
    flex: 1
  : Row
    direction: horizontal
    mainAxisAlignment: start
    crossAxisAlignment: center
    dependencies: [Directionality]
    renderObject: RenderFlex#afc02
  : GetMaterialApp
  : MyApp
  ...
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TextField file:///Users/akbarpulatov/Desktop/tests/move_me_delivery/lib/components/search_field.dart:49:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugCheckHasMaterial.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:27:7)
#1      debugCheckHasMaterial (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:48:4)
#2      _TextFieldState.build (package:flutter/src/material/text_field.dart:1116:12)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message you got already explains the problem very well, so I'll just give you a solution. Wrap the child of your `Hero` widget in a `Material`:

```
Hero(
  tag: "search",
  child: Material(
    type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        //TextField(),
        //GestureDetector(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: thank you dude, it solved the problem but created questions about how Hero works. So does it detached from the widget tree while animating?

Comment: The [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations#behind-the-scenes) gives a good explanation. They also tell you the reason in the error message: "In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them."

Comment: The part getting animated isn't in the old widget tree, so it doesn't have the `Material` parents like `Scaffold`. Thus, you need to provide one within the `Hero`.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative fix is to wrap the Inkwell in Material when the transition occurs:

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34119

```
Hero(
    tag: "image",
    flightShuttleBuilder: (BuildContext flightContext, Animation<double> animation, HeroFlightDirection flightDirection, BuildContext fromHeroContext, BuildContext toHeroContext) => Material(child: toHeroContext.widget),
...
```

Comment: I would add `type` property set to `MaterialType.transparency` for better resutl